# How to sum divs values from different divs with the same class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a cart block and i want to get the total price of each "item-row" div using jQuery but i can't make it work the right way. More specifically for the first item the total price must be: 100.40€ + 5.00€  +15.00€  +15.00€ = 135.40€
Instead i get a sum of 200.80€ on both item's total price!

As you can see from the code below the results are completely wrong. 
What i am missing?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sum = 0.00;

  $(".item-row").each(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(".cart-item-price").text());
    if (val) {
      val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\$/, ""));
      sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
    }
  });

  $(".item-total-price").html('<span style="color:red;float:left;">Item total price: </span>' + sum.toFixed(2) + "€");

  /* alert(sum); */
});
```

```css
.item-title {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.cart-item-price {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100px;
}

.item-extra {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.item-total-price {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-row">
  <div class="item-title">iPhone 12: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">100.40€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Case: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">5.00€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Color Red: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">15.00€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Power Bank: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">15.00€</div>
  <div class="item-total-price"></div>
</div>
<div class="item-row">
  <div class="item-title">Samsung Galaxy S88: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">982.40€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Case: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">3.80€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Color Red: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">9.00€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Power Bank: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">15.40€</div>
  <div class="item-total-price"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. The main issue is that you need to select the relevant `.cart-item.price` and `.item-total-price` elements within the *current* `.item-row` only. To do that you can use `$(this).find()`.

Secondly you need another loop through all of the `.cart-item-price` elements within the current `.item-row` to calculate the `sum`.

Finally you need to place `var sum = 0` within the outer `each()` loop. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".item-row").each(function() {
    var sum = 0.00;
    $(this).find('.cart-item-price').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).text().trim()) || 0;
    });

    $(this).find(".item-total-price").html('<span>Item total price: </span>' + sum.toFixed(2) + "€");
  });
});
```

```css
.item-title {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.cart-item-price {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100px;
}

.item-extra {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.item-total-price {
  width: 250px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-total-price span {
  color: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-row">
  <div class="item-title">iPhone 12: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">100.40€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Case: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">5.00€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Color Red: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">15.00€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Power Bank: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">15.00€</div>
  <div class="item-total-price"></div>
</div>
<div class="item-row">
  <div class="item-title">Samsung Galaxy S88: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">982.40€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Case: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">3.80€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Color Red: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">9.00€</div>
  <br/>
  <div class="item-extra">Power Bank: </div>
  <div class="cart-item-price">15.40€</div>
  <div class="item-total-price"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Rory McCrossan   Thanks for your answer but it works partly. At the second item in your code the price is wrong again.  It must be 1010.60€ instead of 982.40€

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you so much for your effort. I ll select your answer as the right one

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all the prices and adding them up ( from both rows ) and then you select both `total-price` and set the same sum to both. That's why it doesn't work.

You need to change your logic. The start is good. Iterate through rows with `each`

But then select the prices that are corresponding to that specific row. So make use of `this` keyword. And the same with the `total-price`

See below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(".item-row").each(function() {
    var sum = 0.00;
    var itemPrices = $(this).find(".cart-item-price")
    $(itemPrices).each(function() {
      var val = $.trim( $(this).text() );
      if ( val ) {
          val = parseFloat( val.replace( /^\$/, "" ) );
          sum += !isNaN( val ) ? val : 0;
       }
     })
    var totalPrice = $(this).find(".item-total-price");
    totalPrice.html('<span style="color:red;float:left;">Item total price: </span>' + sum.toFixed(2) + "€");
  });

       
/* alert(sum); */

});
```

```css
.item-title { 
float:left;
width:150px;

}

.cart-item-price{
float:left;
text-align:right;
width:100px;

}

.item-extra { 
float:left;
width:150px;
font-weight:200;
}

.item-total-price {
  width:250px;
  text-align:right;
  margin-top:25px;
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  overflow:hidden;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-row">

<div class="item-title">iPhone 12: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">100.40€</div>
<br/>
<div class="item-extra">Case: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">5.00€</div>
<br/>
<div class="item-extra">Color Red: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">15.00€</div>
<br/>
<div class="item-extra">Power Bank: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">15.00€</div>

<div class="item-total-price"></div>

</div>


<div class="item-row">

<div class="item-title">Samsung Galaxy S88: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">982.40€</div>
<br/>
<div class="item-extra">Case: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">3.80€</div>
<br/>
<div class="item-extra">Color Red: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">9.00€</div>
<br/>
<div class="item-extra">Power Bank: </div>
<div class="cart-item-price">15.40€</div>

<div class="item-total-price"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: The second item's total price is wrong: It must be 1010.60 not 1146.00 ! :(

Comment: @Designer It is : 1010.60 :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with javascript.
Inside $(".item-row").each() function you should get all **.cart-item-price** divs and sum up those using one more inner .each() function.

Just replace your javascript with below, and everything should work as expected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $( ".item-row" ).each(function( index ) {
     var sum = 0.00;
     $( this ).find( ".cart-item-price" ).each(function( index2 ) { 
        var val = $( this ).text();
        if (val) {
           val = parseFloat(val.replace(/^\$/, ""));
           sum += !isNaN(val) ? val : 0;
        }
     });

     $( this ).find( ".item-total-price").first().html('<span style="color:red;float:left;">Item total price: </span>' + sum.toFixed(2) + "€");

  })
});
```